# Xcode editor taking too much time in compiling

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm a newbie in Swift. I just created a new single view project in xcode9.3 and tried building it and its taking forever to compile.

Why is this so?

Comment: Please see my answer and let me know if you have any questions :)

Answer (score 0):

I have had something similar to this, and I found that restarting Xcode a few times should solve the problem.

If this doesn't work, you might want to download the [latest version of Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/download/). As of now, I think the latest non-beta version is 9.4.1.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue in the past.
The swift compiler have some issues with specific code styles which makes it sometimes compile files even slower.

In the end we quit Swift as a development language and moved to React Native and back to Objective-C on iOS projects as swift became too cumbersome.

Moving forward, you might want to look at some of guides out there.

This two looks promising.

- https://medium.com/rocket-fuel/optimizing-build-times-in-swift-4-dc493b1cc5f5
- https://github.com/fastred/Optimizing-Swift-Build-Times

Back when I was working on swift, this was guide we were using as a guideline:
[Part 1](https://medium.com/@RobertGummesson/regarding-swift-build-time-optimizations-fc92cdd91e31)
[Part 2](https://medium.com/swift-programming/swift-build-time-optimizations-part-2-37b0a7514cbe)